# Query customized model in Alfresco

Tags: java, lucene, alfresco

I've some customized models into Alfresco and I need to extract the aspect information and the content from Repository.

I need, passing the keywords and the model name (it's an aspect), to extract content or the aspects associated to the model.

```
search/{keywords}?model={model?}
```

this is the javascript I'm using to extract the content passing the model

```
var docs = search.luceneSearch("@kd\\:commonname_content_type_tag:\"" + model + "\"");
```

How can I concatenate two aspects properties?

I did it into Java but the syntax in Javascript seems quite different:

```
queryString  = "+TYPE:\"" + Constants.createQNameString(CommonAspects.NAMESPACE_KD_CONTENT_MODEL, DrugModel.TYPE_SUPPLIER) + "\" ";
queryString += "+@kd\\:SupplierID:" + drugBrandNameBean.getSupplierID();
String supplier = contentQuery.getUUID(queryString);
```

Another question, how can I process the Javascript docs? Can I access to my aspects?

I tried something like that but it didn't works:

```
var docs = search.luceneSearch("@kd\\:commonname_content_type_tag:\"" + model + "\"");    
for (var i=0; i<docs.length; i++) {
    log += "Searching " + commonName + " - Name: " + docs[i].name + "\tPath: " + docs[i].displayPath;
    log += "\tType: " + docs[i].commonname_content_type_tag + "\r\n";
}
```

The rows extracted are correct but the commonname_content_type_tag properties is always not defined:

```
Searching acarbose - Name: exenatide - Contraindication Path: /Company Home/CommonName  Type: undefined
```

Thanks for the help!

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
docs[i].properties["kd:commonname_content_type_tag"]
```

Comment: Perfect! Where can I find some informat object doc strucutre (returned by search.luceneSearc()) ?